# What does 記 mean in a 公正証書 (notarial document)?

Tags: kanji, abbreviations

What does 記 mean when is placed between different articles/paragraphs of a 公正証書 (notarial document)? Here's an example: https://goo.gl/yVYQe7 (I have omitted names and addresses for privacy).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not really sure how I'd translate it as a single word, but the idea is "recorded" ... meaning here something like declared assets that fit under the above section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well 大辞泉 has the definition

> 文体の一。事実をしるすもの。

for 記. So it is just a writing style for indicating factual stuff.

Answer (score 3):

That format is common in a less formal document or announcement -- for example, company-wide fire drill in the following week.

> http://okwave.jp/qa/q2066314.html -- 文書を作成するときに、挨拶や文書の主旨をまず書いて、その他の内容を箇条書きにするときに用いられる手法です。

---

> ……について、下記のとおり実施します。
>
> 記
>
> １.　日時 
>    ２.　場所 
>    ３.　…

Maybe this 記 means "Note" or "N.B." or "noted" or "hereby noted".